# File changes permission after writing block of byte

Tags: java, utf-8, readonly, randomaccessfile

I am getting issue when trying to read and write to the same file using RandomAcessFile.

I am reading block of 16 bytes from a file and write them in the same file on given position (eg. 256-th).

The problem is on `ra.write(b)` line. When the following line is execute i got a message on the text editor Kate (I am using Linux Manjaro) saying:

> The file /home/mite/IdeaProjects/IspitJuni2015/dat.txt was opened with UTF-8 encoding but contained invalid characters.
>   It is set to read-only mode, as saving might destroy its content.
>   Either reopen the file with the correct encoding chosen or enable the read-write mode again in the tools menu to be able to edit it.

and it turns on read-only mode. 
Also I tried manually to uncheck the read-only permission in Kate but it's not working either. What seems to be the problem?

```
 public static byte[] read(long i) throws IOException{
    File in = new File("./dat.txt");
    RandomAccessFile ra = new RandomAccessFile(in,"rw");
    byte[] readObj= new byte[16];
    if (i>in.length()/16)
    {
        return null;
    }
    ra.seek(i*16);
    ra.read(readObj);
    ra.close();
    return readObj;
}
public static void write(long i, byte[] obj) throws IOException{
    File out=new File("./dat.txt");
    RandomAccessFile ra=new RandomAccessFile(out,"rw");
    if (!out.exists())
    {
        out.createNewFile();
    }
    long size=out.length();
    if (i*16>size)
    {
        ra.seek(out.length());
        for (long j=size;j<i*16;j+=16)
        {
            byte[] b=new byte[16];
            ra.write(b);
        }
    }
    ra.seek((i)*16);
    System.out.println(new String(obj));
    ra.write(obj);
    ra.close();
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    write(35,read(4));
}
```

Comment: The `out.exists()/createNewFile()` block is pointless at best, but especially so *after* you've constructed the `RandomAccessFile`. Remove it.

Comment: Hi Mitko. An answer has been made below, are you able to reply to it, and to reply as to whether it has helped you?

Comment: @halfer Hi, I leave replay and possible solution. You can look bellow

Comment: OK, thanks. It is customary, though not strictly mandatory, to ping the person who helped you as well. It is good to express some gratitude, or to comment on what final solution worked for you, so posters know their efforts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your replies. I figured out the problem.

Sometimes text editors are adding one extra byte at the end of the file which is not supported as byte in Java. Usually this is `EOF` byte and is treated as UTF-8 which Java only accepts writing/reading ASCI bytes, except manipulating through `writeUTF()` method.

Also this byte is invisible in text editors and that was the reason why I write this post.

It took me two days to find out what is the issue, but if someone gets stuck here keep in mind the EOF byte.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand what your editor tells you.

First of all, not every possible sequence of bytes is a valid UTF-8 string, see for example ["UTF-8 decoder capability and stress test"](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-test.txt). So when you copy 16 bytes from one place of UTF-8 file to another you might get a file which no longer contains a valid UTF-8 text.

I suspect that you have the same file opened in Kate to see results of your editing. What the editors says to you is that it noticed that the file you opened is not a valid UTF-8 file and thus it doesn't know how to handle it correctly and thus to prevent accidental damage to your potentially precious data which now looks as binary (not text) to the editor, the editor refuses to save anything from UI back to that file. This doesn't change any permission on file-system level and probably other (dumber) editors will not warn you about such possible corruptions.